# Open UIDatePicker programmatically in iOS 14

Tags: swift, uikit, uidatepicker, ios14

I have this normal `UIDatePicker` (sorry that it's not in English, please ignore that):

[image: my date picker]

But the problem is that it only appears when I'm pressing the Date Picker:

[image]

And I wanted to know how to show the Date Picker like in the first image (that it's covering all the screen with the blur effect) **only with code**, so the user won't need to press the Date Picker to show the date selector. Thanks.

Comment: How did you create that UI? storyboard? code? do you have an outlet?

Comment: Storyboard, and yes I do have an outlet. But the menu from the first image is generated when I’m pressing the compact menu

Comment: Are you find the solution?

Comment: no, not yet .  .

Comment: You can force an object to become the first responder with `yourPicker.becomeFirstResponder()`. This should more or less simulate a tap on the date field.

Comment: @SanzioAngeli that doesn't work

Comment: Subclass a `UITextView` and `DateFormatter` to show the date formatted how you want it, make it editable, set your date picker as the `inputView` of the text view, and then `yourtextView.becomeFirstResponder()`. This works, I have it currently implemented.

Comment: @SanzioAngeli Please submit this as an answer and provide more details

Comment: After further testing to try and make an answer, you are correct this does not work. This only works for the `.wheels` style (which is how I had mine styled). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Look at the solution below using `GraphicalDatePickerStyle` from SwiftUI.

Comment: Good question. I haven't found the answer yet. But I found how to close the full screen calendar controller. After selecting the date we can hide it (`_UIDatePickerIOSCompactViewController`) using simple `dismiss()` (find top vc)

Comment: @SoftDesigner I want to try what you suggested but I can't find how to do that. Please share some more code?

Comment: @אוריorihpt check the code here: https://gist.github.com/vvit/22b33b779ba85db85e02bc5bcc5979a0

Answer (score 15):

You can use a datePicker with `.compact` style and put a `UILabel` on top of it and give it a background color to hide the `datePicker` behind it, and make sure the label user interaction is disabled then you should be able to tap on the datePicker and it will show the modal and then the value changed of the datePicker you can use your own date formatter to set the text of the label accordingly, you might also both the datePicker and the label inside a `UIView` and make it clip to bounds

Comment: This is a clever workaround. It worked for me. I had two date pickers side by side. Just had to ensure they were lined up properly so the clicks from the (smaller) labels would pass through.

Comment: I was using this workaround and hiding the label when the datePicker was tapped, but iOS 15 caused me to no longer capture taps from the date picker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69620836/uitapgesturerecognizer-on-uidatepicker-not-working-in-ios-15

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem. Im using following hack:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact

// Removes Labels
datePicker.subviews.forEach({ $0.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() }) })
```

Then I simply add this date picker on top of a view, which should open this popup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I won't mark this as accepted, because it don't answer all of my question. The user still have to press the Date Picker for it to open. I wanted a solution that instead of the user pressing I will do it only with code.

Comment: I think this is the closest one can get to achieve this functionality

Comment: I see the labels disappearing, but the calendar doesn't appear.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately it's not possible to programatically display the date selector popup, at least not resorting to hacks that might result in your app being rejected:

- the UIDatePicker control doesn't expose any events that can be programatically triggered via `sendActions(for:)` - `allControlEvents` returns an empty option set
- programatically simulating a user click is officially impossible on iOS - there is no public API to achieve this, all workarounds imply resorting to private API's
- if the above wouldn't be enough, the UI structure of UIDatePicker is composed of private classes:

  [image] [image]

The conclusion is that in its current state, the `UIDatePicker` UI can be controlled only via user interactions. Maybe this will change in the future, for example `UIButton`'s expose actions for triggering the same behaviour as when the user tapped the button, so maybe `UIDatePicker` will expose such actions in the future.

Comment: Nobody is rejecting apps unless they crash.

Comment: @Dmitry using private (iOS SDK) API's is guaranteed to result in your binary being automatically rejected by the tools that run once a build was submitted to AppStore.

Comment: Never seen this to happen when it was the case.

Answer (score 8):

It's impossible to open a `UIDatePicker` with `UIKit14` from within the code

- `UIDatePicker` has no API for doing this
- `UIKit` doesn't allow us to create a `UIEvents` or `UITouch` object which has any impact on `UIKit`.

Comment: I know that, I'm searching for a workaround that will give the same result as pressing the Date Picker

Comment: @TLGCodin' It's impossible

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: I have created a bounty and will be glad to see someone will show me that I was wrong

Comment: I have a question to maybe help you with this, what will trigger the date picker to appear ? I know you said you wanted programmatically, but there has to be an action behind this. Will the user tap on anything ? Will the app open it at some specific point or behavior?

Comment: @JArango The trigger in my specific code is pressing a UIButton. But I asked in general how to do this with code, no matter what is the trigger

Comment: I can tell that you can't do something, but you never can tell that it's impossible. All is possible in this world.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is still valid, but you can make use of the `.inline` style of new UIDatePicker. Then use your own view and animations to mimic the appearance of the DatePicker from `.compact` style.

```
let secondDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
secondDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
self.view.addSubview(secondDatePicker)

secondDatePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
secondDatePicker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
secondDatePicker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: This is pretty clever if you can size the popover well

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE: THIS IS NOT WORKING ANYMORE ON iOS 15.**

@Amr Mohamed 's answer is clever by putting a label on the date picker view, but this also causes a glitch when tapping the date picker view, when the date picker vc animates out, you can also see the date picker.

So we need to "hide" the date picker view but also leave it interactive. (We can't just use `isHidden = true` or `alpha = 0`, otherwise it's not tappable anymore)

This is how I did in my project:

```
extension UIView {
    func loopDescendantViews(_ closure: (_ subView: UIView) -> Void) {
        for v in subviews {
            closure(v)
            v.loopDescendantViews(closure)
        }
    }
}

let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
datePicker.loopDescendantViews {
    $0.alpha = $0 is UIControl ? 1 : 0
}
```

Then you can put this invisible date picker on top of your label/other view. once you tap the label (actually tapped the date picker), the date picker vc animates out.

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Comment: This code does not work because views whose Alpha gets set to 0, become not clickable

Answer (score 2):

You can set the preferred style of the date picker to "inline" from the storyboard. By doing this, you will directly get the full screen for date selection directly.

here is how the date picker looks for preferred style "compact"( the one you have):

[image: date picker with preferred style as compact]

vs "inline" ( the one you are looking for):

[image: date picker with preferred style as inline]

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure we're not missing the obvious here, the ***`.inline`*** style displays the full calendar without the user needing to click a date or time label. With that ability one could arrange any behavior they want with regard to displaying the calendar and selected/default dates, etc...

Comment: yea we know that.

Comment: It's just that the workarounds & hacks for programmatically triggering it in compact mode are so draconian that one needs to know there's a solid way to achieve it, which I didn't from reading the docs too fast because the default mode is compact. So I thought you *had* to click the label to see the calendar. So even though you know and people who are really focusing on your question and all the details may assume all of this, it is possible some people will benefit from someone pointing it out.  In fact I was very close to using a 3rd party datepicker before I found .inline does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a way to make it work for both iOS 14 and iOS 15, but since it reads the hierarchy it may stop working with any upcoming iOS release:

```swift
// The callback from your tap gesture or whatever you use:
func handleTapOnView() {
    let datePickerGesture: UIGestureRecognizer? = {
        guard let compactView = datePicker.subviews.first else { return nil }
        // iOS 15
        if let dateLabel = compactView.subviews
                .first(where: { String(describing: type(of: $0)).hasSuffix("DateLabel") }),
           let gesture = dateLabel.gestureRecognizers?.first {
            return gesture
        }
        // iOS 14
        if let gesture = compactView.gestureRecognizers?.last {
            return gesture
        }
        return nil
    }()
    datePickerGesture?.state = .ended
}
```

For the 'iOS 15' part of the code use `.hasSuffix("DateLabel")` if you want to focus the date selection part, and `.hasSuffix("TimeLabel")` for focusing the time selection part.

Answer (score -1):

Define these variables

```
var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
var datePickerConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var blurEffectView: UIView!
```

Then create a function `showDatePicker()` that you call to trigger the display of the `UIDatePicker`. First, create a subview with the same size of his parent View and give it a blur effect. Then add the `UIDatePicker`, as a subview on top of the blurred view.

```
   func showDatePicker() {
        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker?.date = Date()
        datePicker?.locale = .current
        datePicker?.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateSet), for: .valueChanged)
        addDatePickerToSubview()
    }

    func addDatePickerToSubview() {
        guard let datePicker = datePicker else { return }
        // Give the background Blur Effect
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.regular)
        blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
        datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        centerDatePicker()
        view.bringSubviewToFront(datePicker)
    }

    func centerDatePicker() {
        guard let datePicker = datePicker else { return }
        // Center the Date Picker
        datePickerConstraints.append(datePicker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor))
        datePickerConstraints.append(datePicker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor))
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(datePickerConstraints)
    }
```

And finally, once a date a selected in the `UIDatePicker`

```
 @objc func dateSet() {
        // Get the date from the Date Picker and put it in a Text Field
        compactDatePicker.date = datePicker.date
        blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
        datePicker.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Not entirely sure about the blurr effect so hopefully someone can build on this solution.

Comment: But there is no `dateTextField`. There is a compact date picker, and the idea is to open it as if the user had tapped it.

Comment: i am not aware of any method to "fake" a user tapping the compact date picker, so i thought with the code above i would fake it by presenting another date picker in inline style then when dismissed, set the value of the original compact date picker to that of the one just presented.

Comment: a lot of extra code - "?" is extra because you are sure your date picker is created and exists in this chuck of code. `guard let datePicker ...` is extra too because blur and date picker constraints are extra without of date picker by itself. `bringSubviewToFront` is strange too because your view is already added over other views. Your constraints are insufficient and your inline date picker will jump with them.

Answer (score -1):

I think the only non-hacky approach is to create a new view controller, add a UIDatePicker instance in it with the embedded style, then present the controller modally or as a popover.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63333081/14016301

Answer (score -1):

It works to switch to the old style of date picker:

```
        if (@available(iOS 13.4, *)) {
            [datePicker setPreferredDatePickerStyle:UIDatePickerStyleWheels];
        }
```

Comment: Sometimes the correct answer lays beyond the scope of the initial question.

Comment: Hippity hoppity this answer is not your property https://stackoverflow.com/a/64710218/14016301

Answer (score -1):

Date picker changed in iOS v14.0 before that it was an inline wheel.
Now in iOS v14.0 what you can do is tell it to be inline and it will show the calendar inline (no popup):

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
     datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.inline         
}
```

Note: you may need to fix the frame size as the datepicker will look different in iOS 13 (wheel) and iOS 14 (calendar), so you will probably need an "else" for version 13..

Answer (score -1):

I am using this extension to set `clear` colour on every subview of the `UIDatePicker` and then use a `UILabel` as suggested by others.

```
extension UIDatePicker {
  
  private func traverse(view: UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
      self.traverse(view: subview)

      // Setting alpha to 0 disables userInteraction.
      subview.alpha = 0.02
    }
  }
  
  func paintClear() {
    self.traverse(view: self)
  }
  
}
```