# SwiftUI UIDatePicker .compact doesn't go directly to pop-up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uidatepicker

I have created a custom DatePicker using `UIDatePicker` and when I select the field it displays the date and time as an option at the bottom of the screen without going directly to the pop-up.  Not sure how to describe it so please see the image below:

[image: DatePicker view]

Please see my code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomDateTimePicker: View {
@State private var date: Date?
@State private var time: String? = "Time"

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Image("Time")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 22.0, height: 22.0, alignment: .center)
        DateField("", date: self.$date)
            .font(.system(size: 19, weight: .light, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
    }.padding()
    .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
    .background(Color.white)
    .cornerRadius(8)
    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 30, x: 0 , y: 15)
}
}

class DateTextField: UITextField {
// MARK: - Public properties
@Binding var date: Date?

// MARK: - Initializers
init(date: Binding<Date?>) {
    self._date = date
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    
    if let date = date.wrappedValue {
        self.datePickerView.date = date
    }
    
    self.datePickerView.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    self.inputView = datePickerView
    self.tintColor = .clear
    self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .medium)
}

@available(*, unavailable)
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

// MARK: - Private properties
private lazy var datePickerView: UIDatePicker = {
    let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    datePickerView.minuteInterval = 5
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        datePickerView.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
        datePickerView.sizeToFit()
    } else {
        datePickerView.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    }
    return datePickerView
}()

// MARK: - Private methods
@objc func dateChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    self.date = sender.date
}
}

struct DateField: UIViewRepresentable {
// MARK: - Public properties
@Binding var date: Date?

// MARK: - Initializers
init<S>(_ title: S, date: Binding<Date?>, formatter: DateFormatter = .yearMonthDay) where S: StringProtocol {
    self.placeholder = String(title)
    self._date = date
    self.textField = DateTextField(date: date)
    self.formatter = formatter
}

// MARK: - Public methods
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<DateField>) ->  UITextField {
    textField.placeholder = placeholder
    return textField
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context:   UIViewRepresentableContext<DateField>) {
    if let date = date {
        uiView.text = formatter.string(from: date)
    }
}


// MARK: - Private properties
private var placeholder: String
private let formatter: DateFormatter
private let textField: DateTextField
}

extension DateFormatter {
    static var yearMonthDay: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"
        return formatter
    }
}

struct CustomDateTimePicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomDateTimePicker()
    }
}
```

How can I have the compact menu be shown when after clicking on my field instead of having to choose the date/time at the bottom?

Comment: If you show us some code that produces a minimal reproducible product we might be able to help. Something we can copy and paste and see what you are talking about. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've added code to reproduce now.  Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Compact DatePicker you can't automatically show the calendar without selecting it from the part that show up at the bottom.
[Open UIDatePicker programmatically in iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63331669/open-uidatepicker-programmatically-in-ios-14)

You can (if the 5 minute interval isn't a requirement) use `GraphicalDatePickerStyle` which shows a very similar calendar.

```
struct ParentDatePicker: View  {
    @State var showGraphical: Bool = false
    @State var currentDate: Date = Date()
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"
        return formatter
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            showGraphical.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Label(
                title: { Text("\(currentDate, formatter: dateFormatter)") },
                icon: { Image(systemName: "clock") })
        })
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 30, x: 0 , y: 15)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showGraphical, content: {
            CusDatePicker(currentDate: $currentDate)
        })
    }
}
struct CusDatePicker: View {
    @Binding var currentDate: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker
        DatePicker("Date", selection: $currentDate, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
            //.datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
    }
}

struct CusDatePicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ParentDatePicker()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Doesn't this gives error `Missing argument for parameter 'currentDate' in call` ?

Comment: @Nij look at how `ParentDatePicker` is calling `CusDatePicker` you need a source of truth

Comment: Alright. You called `ParentDatePicker` in `CusDatePicker ` preview provider, what if I want to use CusDatePicker from any other class? can it be used from multiple class?

Comment: Not a class any SwiftUI struct just add the source of truth like it is done in the sheet. Binding is a two-way connection @Nij