# Show DatePicker as popup instead of having it show inline

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker

Right now, I have `DatePicker` set up in my SwiftUI code to just always show inline with the rest of the UI:

```
DatePicker(
    "",
    selection: $selectedDate,
    displayedComponents: .date
)
.labelsHidden()
.datePickerStyle(.graphical)
```

Instead I'd like to show the DatePicker over-top the rest of the UI, sort of like an Alert with a blurred background.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried ```.compact``` style? When it gets focus, the graphical picker pops up like you were describing.

Comment: @BenzyNeez Yes, but I have a custom button that opens the DatePicker on tap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384408/swiftui-uidatepicker-compact-doesnt-go-directly-to-pop-up/65385410#65385410

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to show the picker when a button is tapped then the post [How to trigger SwiftUI DatePicker Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75073023/20386264) describes how it can be done. See also [How to make a button (or any other element) show SwiftUI's DatePicker popup on tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65797437/20386264) for more suggestions.

You also said you wanted to blur the background.

The solution below shows a date picker with style `.graphical` as a layer in a `ZStack` when a button is tapped. In addition:

- an `.onChange` handler hides the picker if the date is changed
- the same flag that is used to control the visibility of the picker is also used to control a blur effect
- another semi-transparent layer is shown between the main content and the picker, to dim the main content
- the intermediate layer has an `.onTapGesture` handler, which makes it possible to hide the picker without selecting a date.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    @State private var selectedDate: Date = .now
    @State private var showingPicker = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Form {
                Text("\(selectedDate)")
                Button("Show date picker") {
                    showingPicker = true
                }
                Text(loremIpsum)
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedDate) {
                showingPicker = false
            }
            .blur(radius: showingPicker ? 2 : 0)

            if showingPicker {
                Color.primary
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .opacity(0.1)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showingPicker = false
                    }
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: $selectedDate,
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                .padding(8)
                .background(.bar)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .shadow(radius: 3)
                .transition(.scale)
                .padding()
                .padding(.top, 90)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: showingPicker)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]