# SwiftUI DatePicker Programatic Selection

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

When the user selects the "Yes" button I want to show the activated DatePicker programmatically and then once they've selected a date to show the only the DatePicker in its non-presented state instead of the "Yes" button.

How can I programmatically display the DatePicker and switch it with the "Yes" button?

[image: Date Selection]

Comment: What have you tired? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: It's impossible in iOS 14 - similar question [How to make a button (or any other element) show SwiftUI's DatePicker popup on tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65797437/8697793)