# SwiftUI Date Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui

DatePicker on Button Click.

I already tried many code but none of them worked for me,

```
HStack {
   Image(systemName: "calendar")
        
    Button(action: {
       
    }, label: {
         Text("Today")
           .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))          
    })
    
    Spacer()
    Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
}
```

that's my button code,
I want to implement the date when user tapped on Today text.
Really want your help

Comment: What does *implement the date* mean? The question needs a bit more information.

Comment: I want to implement DatePicker when user tapped on today text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65797437/how-to-make-a-button-or-any-other-element-show-swiftuis-datepicker-popup-on-t/65799547#65799547

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DatePicker` provided by SwiftUI.

Declare state variables - one to store the date and another to conditionally show or hide the `DatePicker`.

```
@State var date = Date()
@State var isDatePickerVisible = false
```

Set `isDatePickerVisible` to `true` when the user clicks on the button.

```
Button(action: {
       isDatePickerVisible = true
}, label: {
     Text("Today")
       .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))          
})
```

Show the DatePicker when the `isDatePickerVisible` flag is set to `true`.
Clicking on the done button will hide the `DatePicker` again.

```
if isDatePickerVisible {
    HStack {
        DatePicker("", selection: $date)
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            .frame(maxHeight: 400)

        Button("Done", action: {
            isDatePickerVisible = false
        })
    }
}
```

You can also display the selected date in a `Text` using the following code.

```
Text("Date is \(date.formatted(date: .long, time: .omitted))")
```

However, if you want to display the current date when the user clicks on Today instead of letting the user pick a date, use the following code:

```
if isDatePickerVisible {
    Text(Date.now, format: .dateTime.day().month().year())
}
```