# How to make a UIDatePicker label invisible still interactive in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to open a UIDatePicker programatically in my Xamarin.ios project. Unfortunately it is not allowed and there is no public api. But I got some tricks which are native code from [Open UIDatePicker programmatically in iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63331669/open-uidatepicker-programmatically-in-ios-14)
I am trying to implement this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430977/13026962
I managed to add a UIDatePicker on top of my label. This is my code:

```
            lblFromDate.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
            var datePicker = new UIDatePicker(new CGRect(x: lblFromDate.Frame.X, y: 
            lblFromDate.Frame.Y, width: lblFromDate.Frame.Width, height: lblFromDate.Frame.Height));
            datePicker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;
            datePicker.ValueChanged += DatePicker_ValueChanged;
            Add(datePicker);
```

[image]

But I want to hide the date picker somehow but still need that to be interactive so that when tapping on the label (actually tapped the date picker), the date picker animates out.

The second problem is I want to close the calendar modal when any date is tapped. But I found only value changed event. Is it possible to close the calendar modal programmatically, would be a great help for me. Here is the calendar modal that pops up after tapping on the date picker:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first problem:
You can set the datepicker's PerferredDatePickerStyle as compact, and set the color of label which on the datepicker as white to cover the datepicker. Also set label's
enabled as false.
code like:

```
mydatapicker.PerferredDatePickerStyle=UIDatePickerStyle.Compact;
mylabel.BackgroundColor=UIColor.White;
//.....
```

To change it Text, add follow code:

```
mydatapicker.valuechanged+=Datepicker_Valuechanged;
private void Datepicker_Valuechanged(object sender,EventArgs e) 
{mylabel.Text=mydatapicker.Date.ToString();}
```

To your second problem
I am afraid there is no appropriate way  to close the calendar modal when any date is tapped.

Hope these could be helpful to you.

1.In storyboard,set label's enabled as false.
[image]

2.before click

[image]

3.click

[image]

4.after value changed

[image]

5.code behind

[image]

Comment: I think I need to be a more clear. I need the datepicker label which is blue(no variable for that label) to disappear but still interactive. lblFromDate this will stay as it is and will act as the datepicker label. By the way datepicker is on the top subview right now.

Comment: Hi, I edit my answer with some screenshots to make it more clear. @RobinKhan