# UITapGestureRecognizer on UIDatePicker not working in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uidatepicker, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a row for a user to select a date, and I'm using the `UIDatePicker` to do this. When a user taps on it, I want it to change some text on the row as well as open the date picker. This was previously working fine with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on my `UIDatePicker` that could activate some code, but something broke it and now my `UITapGestureRecognizer` is not being recognized at all!

I think it may be iOS 15 that changed something, but looking at the docs I don't see anything really.

Here's what my code is like:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hidePlaceholderLabel))
datePicker.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

My `hidePlaceholderLabel` function is never run. How do I bring this functionality back without creating a custom date picker?

I'm using autolayout and have confirmed via Reveal that my date picker does have a frame and should be tappable.

Answer (score 3):

Add a target for `.editingDidBegin` event on the `UIDatePicker`. This is called when user taps on UIDatePicker elements in order to adjust the date. For me this works very well

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hidePlaceholderLabel), for: .editingDidBegin)
```

Answer (score 0):

UIDatePicker inherits from UIControl, just like UIButton. So instead of adding a tap gesture recognizer, you must add an `addTarget` method:

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hidePlaceholderLabel), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.